# In my application one class cannot be found whose reference I have added in another class

Tags: java, xml, spring

Error creating bean with name 'person' defined in class path resource [config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'add' while setting bean property 'address'

I am getting the above error but cannot understand why it is hapenning.
All of my classes are in the same package.

Below is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean class="com.lcwd.withoutboot.Person" id="person">
    <property name="name" value="Sourabh"/>
    <property name="address" ref="add"/>
</bean>

<bean class="com.lcwd.withoutboot.Address" id="add">
    <property name="city" value="Mumbai"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

App.java

```
public class App 
{ 
public static void main( String[] args ) { 
ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml"); System.out.println( "Hello World!" ); 
Person person=context.getBean("person", Person.class);
 System.out.println(person.getName());
 System.out.println(person.getAddress()); 
} 
}
```

Person.java

```
package com.lcwd.withoutboot;
public class Person { Address address;

public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
}

String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Address.java

```
package com.lcwd.withoutboot;
public class Address { String city;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Address{" +
            "city='" + city + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.lcwd.withoutboot</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringWithoutBoot</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>SpringWithoutBoot</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.9</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To fix this issue, you could add the method `setter` for "city" field in the "Address":

```java
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
```

Or you could create a constructor of class Address:

```java
public Address(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
```

You got this issue because Spring tries to create an instance of the "Address" object for the "add" bean, but the "Address" class does not have a constructor or setter method for the "city" property.
I hope this help!